# WSO2 APIM Authentication

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

1. I have a requirement to authenticate a user who wants to access an API with his credentials (un/pwd) with basic authentication or digest auth
2. Also pass the required credentials(un/pwd) in the request to authenticate the access to backend service

My synapse extracted config looks like this:

```
<filter source="$ctx:AM_KEY_TYPE" regex="PRODUCTION">
<then>
<property name="api.ut.backendRequestTime"
expression="get-property('SYSTEM_TIME')"/>
<property name="password" 
expression="wso2:vault-lookup('PayAdmin--    ZenoAPI51.0')"/>
<property name="unpw" 
expression="fn:concat('user',':',get-property('password'))"/>
<property name="Authorization"
expression="fn:concat('Basic ', base64Encode(get-property('unpw')))"
scope="transport"/>
<send>
<endpoint name="PayAdmin--ZenoAPI5_APIproductionEndpoint_0">
<http uri-template="http://localhost:8080/payment/{uri.var.name}"/>
</endpoint>
</send>
</then>
```

What i want to know is:

```
curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Accept: application/json" --header "Authorization: Bearer 2e13c9b3c8717f43d093cfc7c63994bb" -d "{}" http://<IP address of APIM Server>:8280/Zeno1/1.0.0/payment/name
```

This curl can only take bearer token but how to pass user/pwd for API and user/pwd for backend in the curl

Comment: your requirement is to send the username and password using CURL to the back end, is that right?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your second question:
For Basic Authentication towards the backend you can configure a **general Password** in the Publisher in step Implement -> Show More Options -> Endpoint Security Scheme: set to Secured and provide Credentials
(see: https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Basic+Auth)

If **user specific credentials** have to be provided the user should set the "Authentication: Basic base64(username:password)" in the HTTP header, the header will get passed to the backend.

Comment: Hi For above you mentioned for basic authentication. Can you please explain how to do pass credentials for Digest auth and how to configure it?

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Accept: application/json" --header "Authorization: **Basic** **[base64encode(username:password)]**" -d "{}" http://<IP address of APIM Server>:8280/Zeno1/1.0.0/payment/name
```

[base64encode(username:password)] replace this with base64 encode string of 
"username:password"